# ArgumentException on Adding multiple Parameters in Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, parameters

I am trying to call stored procedure by adding three parameters but I get the following ArgumentException on Adding the second Parameter

> The SqlParameter is already contained by another
>   SqlParameterCollection

Here is the code snippet:

```
using (IDbCommand cmd =Idbconnection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "usp_Get_Products";
    IDataParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@rvcName";
    param.Value = productName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    param.ParameterName = "@rvcCode";
    param.Value = productCode;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    param.ParameterName = "@riProductTypeID";
    param.Value = productTypeID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Product product = new Product(reader["Name"].ToString(), reader["Code"].ToString(), reader["Description"].ToString(), (DateTime)reader["DateCreated"], Convert.ToInt32(reader["pkProductID"]), Convert.ToInt32(reader["ProductTypeID"]), reader["ProductTypeName"].ToString());
            products.Add(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because `param` is already added to the parameter collection. In your code, you're simply changing the values *of the existing object* then trying to re-add it.

You need to create a *new parameter object instance* for each parameter in the collection:

```
IDataParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@rvcName";
param.Value = productName;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param = cmd.CreateParameter(); //create a new instance for the next parameter
param.ParameterName = "@rvcCode";
param.Value = productCode;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param = cmd.CreateParameter(); //create a new instance for the next parameter
param.ParameterName = "@riProductTypeID";
param.Value = productTypeID;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

---

As per your comment, agreed this is not very DRY. But unless you have existing metadata somewhere, it's probably not worth the energy to create a list of throwaway Tuples just to loop over them and create different objects.

You could use the existing [`AddWithValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method (but you have to be careful with `null` for the value, or the parameter will just poof into thin air!):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rvcName", (object)productName ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rvcCode", (object)productCode ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@riProductTypeID", (object)productTypeID ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Again, not quite DRY yet, so you can wrap that in your own method:

```
static void AddParameterWithValue(this IDbCommand cmd, string paramName, object value)
{
    if(paramName == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(paramName));

    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(paramName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            nameof(paramName), 
            paramName, 
            "Parameter name cannot be empty");
    }

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, value ?? DBNull.Value);
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way like looping? It looks kinda messy

Answer (score 0):

you can use `foreach` loop

```
using (IDbCommand cmd =Idbconnection.CreateCommand())
{
    foreach(var item in your data)
    {
        IDataParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = item.(your data here for ParameterName)
        param.Value = item.productCode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
}
```